# Bootstrap, get rid of border of icon in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm working with Bootstrap in React, and I'm trying to implement a password, where there is an icon to click on to toggle between text and password types inside of the input field. I've implemented all of the logic, but the icon/input field has a border so that it look like a button to the right of the input, like so:

[image]

I was wondering how I could get rid of that border separating the two so that it would look like it was inside of the input box to be like this example:

[image]

This is the code I have written with the react hooks replaced

```
import { Icon } from "react-icons-kit";
import { eyeOff } from "react-icons-kit/feather/eyeOff";
import { eye } from "react-icons-kit/feather/eye";

<label>Password</label>
<div className="mb-3 input-group">
    <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter password"
        required
    />
    <span className="input-group-append bg-white">
        <span className="input-group-text bg-transparent">
            <Icon icon={eyeOff} size={15}/>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I've tried to add "border border-right-0" to the input-group div class which seems to do nothing, and also "border border-left-0" to the input-group-append span class, but this seems to create another border around the border that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 5.2 dropped .**input-group-append** and .**input-group-prepend**. You can now just add buttons and .**input-group-text** as direct children of the input groups. If you want to remove border on left or right in Bootstrap 5.2, please, use .**border-start-0** and .**border-end-0**.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="search" class="form-control border-end-0">
  <span class="input-group-text bg-white">
    <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<button styles={{'border': 'none !important'}} className="...bootstrap" />`

I unfortunately do not use bootstrap, but adding in-line styles this way would be more specific than the bootstrap className, until you are able to find the real answer. The '!important' may not be necessary to do achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove `border-radius : 0px` from that icon div, secondly, you can remove border by using this property `border-right:none` for div containing password and `border-left:none` for div containing icon